# How can I connect loose edges?

Tags: mesh, edges

I'm making a model for a voxel style game. I've modeled it in Qubicle and exported it to Blender for the animations. But in my mesh most of the faces or edges are not connected, and I can't find a way for doing it so. That is affecting the mesh light in Unity.

[image: Unlinked Edges]

I've tried with the simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging, but that does not connect it. I've also tried putting new vertices and merging both. But the mesh and the UV maps (directly imported from Qubicle) keeps distorting.

[image: Merge Error]

I don't understand why it's so hard in a so basic mesh. Is there a simple way to do it. I'm desperate, please help!

Comment: If there are edges of the mesh and they simply aren't connected to each other use `W` > *Remove Doubles* to remove double vertices; you may want to change *Threshold* value in operator settings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Remove Doubles.

 In Edit Mode, press  <kbd>A</kbd>  once or twice to select all vertices, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd>  and choose Remove Doubles, this will weld all vertices sharing same location.

Comment: And to add to that, when @Georges says "same location" it means exactly the same location, so if they are even a tiny bit off it will not merge. Select the not merging vertices and turn on vertex snap and bring it to where you want, should fix it.

Comment: @Lukaash in Remove Doubles, a margin can be used for vertices location, I think it might work even if they were a little bit off

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know there was such a big allowance of how far away they can be, never the less, when the difference is visible by the eye and and slightly far away and maybe even different z and x, lock to vertex could be helpful, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Lukaash you're right, it all depends on the mesh, sometimes you have to do things manually, but in this case the mesh isn't that dense, so I think this might work

Comment: Hmm, i suppose i agree.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear from the images what you want to do, they are a bit confusing, but it seems you are missing some patches of mesh or faces.

Your mesh looks quite messy, as suggested before try first removing doubles with <kbd>W</kbd> > Remove Doubles while in edit mode with all vertex selected.
You may also be seeing some normal issues, try unifying normals by entering edit mode, selecting all with <kbd>A</kbd> and the pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals.

After that you can then manually connect any two pieces of geometry with the fill function through the <kbd>F</kbd> key. Select two or more edges, press <kbd>F</kbd> and it will create a face, select two vertex press <kbd>F</kbd> and it will connect them with an edge.

If you have two edge loops with the same ammount of eges you may also use the *Bridge* operator to connect them with <kbd>B</kbd> key.